# Put a variable inside a string that is used as a json format

Tags: c#, string, variables

The code under is using a RestApi and is working.
What I want to do is to put the variable `topPlayer` at the string `"dani2"` place. I searched in the net and the ways I found may affect the structure of string message which is necessarily that way. 
Can you suggest me how to put the variable `topPlayer` inside the string message?

```
public class Test2 : MonoBehaviour, IInputClickHandler
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public string topPlayer = PlayerPrefs.GetString("TopPlayer");

    public void OnInputClicked(InputClickedEventData eventData)
    {
        //UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://hipchat.getconnected.it/v2/room/91/message", formData);
        StartCoroutine(dani());
    }

    IEnumerator dani()
    {
        //string message = "{ \"message\": \"dani2\"}";
        string message = "{ \"message\": \"topPlayer\"}";
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://hipchat.getconnected.it/xxx", message);
        request.SetRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer xxx");
        request.SetRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        UploadHandlerRaw upHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(data);
        upHandler.contentType = "application/json";
        request.uploadHandler = upHandler;

        yield return request.Send();

        if (request.isError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
string message = string.Format("{ \"message\": \"{0}\"}",topPlayer);
```

Comment: The outermost braces need to be escaped to avoid `FormatException`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MLir1Z

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of injecting a variable's value into a string. The one suitable for any .NET version is using `String.Format` version.

However, you need to escape the variable's value before injecting it in order to avoid invalid resulting JSON like this `{ "message": "a"b"}` (if `topPlayer` was `a"b`). `System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` will help you with escaping:

```
string message = string.Format("{{ \"message\": \"{0}\"}}",
    System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(topPlayer));
```

Please also note that outermost braces doubled (`{{ ... }}`). This is because single braces have special meaning for the `Format` function so they must be escaped by doubling.

Since C# 6.0 you also may use interpolated strings:

```
string message = $"{{ \"message\": \"{System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(topPlayer))}\"}}";
```